# SQLAlchemy association table (association object pattern) raises IntegrityError

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy release 0.8.2 (tried python 2.7.5 and 3.3.2)

I've had to use the association object pattern (for a many-to-many relationship) in my code, but whenever I've been adding an association, it has been raising an IntegrityError exception. This is because instead of executing "INSERT INTO association (left_id, right_id, extra_data) [...]", it instead executes "INSERT INTO association (right_id, extra_data) [...]", which is going to raise an IntegrityError exception since it's missing a primary key.

After trying to narrow down the problem for a while and simplifying the code as much as possible, I found the culprit(s?), but I don't understand why it's behaving this way.

I included my complete code so the reader can test it as is. The class declarations are exactly the same as in the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html#association-object) (with backrefs).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref


Base = declarative_base()

class Association(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'association'
    left_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('left.id'), primary_key=True)
    right_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'), primary_key=True)
    extra_data = Column(String(50))
    child = relationship("Child", backref="parent_assocs")

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    children = relationship("Association", backref="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)



def main():
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    # populate old data
    session.add(Child()) 

    # new data
    p = Parent()
    session.add(p) # Commenting this fixes the error. 
    session.flush()

    # rest of new data
    a = Association(extra_data="some data")
    a.child = session.query(Child).one()
    # a.child = Child() # Using this instead of the above line avoids the error - but that's not what I want. 
    p.children.append(a)
    # a.parent = p # Using this instead of the above line fixes the error! They're logically equivalent. 

    session.add(p)
    session.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So, as mentioned in the comments in the code above, there are three ways to fix/avoid the problem.

1. Don't add the parent to the session before declaring the association
2. Create a new child for the association instead of selecting an already existing child.
3. Use the backref on the association

I don't understand the behaviour of all three cases.

The second case does something different, so it's not a possible solution. I don't understand the behaviour however, and would appreciate an explanation of why the problem is avoided in this case.

I'm thinking the first case may have something to do with "[Object States](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#quickie-intro-to-object-states)", but I don't know exactly what's causing it either. Oh, and adding `session.autoflush=False` just before the first occurrence of `session.add(p)` also fixes the problem which adds to my confusion.

For the third case, I'm drawing a complete blank since they should be logically equivalent.

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what happens here is that when you call upon `p.children.append()`, SQLAlchemy can't append to a plain collection without loading it first.  As it goes to load, autoflush kicks in - you know this because in your stack trace you will see a line like this:

```
File "/Users/classic/dev/sqlalchemy/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1183, in _autoflush
  self.flush()
```

Your Association object is then flushed here in an incomplete state; it's in the session in the first place because when you say `a.child = some_persistent_child`, an event appends `a` to the `parent_assocs` collection of `Child` which then *cascades* the `Association` object into the session (see [Controlling Cascade on Backrefs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html?highlight=no_autoflush#controlling-cascade-on-backrefs) for some background on this, and one possible solution).

But without affecting any relationships, the easiest solution when you have this chicken/egg sort of problem is to temporarily disable autoflush using [no_autoflush](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html?highlight=no_autoflush#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.no_autoflush):

```
with session.no_autoflush:
    p.children.append(a)
```

by disabling the autoflush when p.children is loaded, your pending object `a` is not flushed; it is then associated with the already persistent `Parent` (because you've added and flushed that already) and is ready for INSERT.

this allows your test program to succeed.